# Prevent show/hide in parent of tree menu

Tags: javascript, menu, tree

How to prevent show/hide action in text of this tree menu?

When I click the `Tech` or `Employees`, it toggle show/hide action instead go to the link with `a href` tag. I just need when people click the glyphicon to toggle show/hide action in this case.

Thanks for any suggestion.

```js
$.fn.extend({
    treed: function (o) {
      
      var openedClass = 'glyphicon-minus-sign';
      var closedClass = 'glyphicon-plus-sign';
      
      if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
        if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
        openedClass = o.openedClass;
        }
        if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
        closedClass = o.closedClass;
        }
      };
      
        //initialize each of the top levels
        var tree = $(this);
        tree.addClass("tree");
        tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
            var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
            branch.prepend("<i class='indicator glyphicon " + closedClass + "'></i>");
            branch.addClass('branch');
            branch.on('click', function (e) {
                if (this == e.target) {
                    var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                    icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                    $(this).children().children().toggle();
                }
            })
            branch.children().children().toggle();
        });
        //fire event from the dynamically added icon
      tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            $(this).closest('li').click();
        });
      });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
        tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
        tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }
});

//Initialization of treeviews

$('#tree1').treed();

$('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'glyphicon-folder-open', closedClass:'glyphicon-folder-close'});

$('#tree3').treed({openedClass:'glyphicon-chevron-right', closedClass:'glyphicon-chevron-down'});
```

```css
.tree, .tree ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none
}
.tree ul {
    margin-left:1em;
    position:relative
}
.tree ul ul {
    margin-left:.5em
}
.tree ul:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    border-left:1px solid
}
.tree li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 1em;
    line-height:2em;
    color:#369;
    font-weight:700;
    position:relative
}
.tree ul li:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:10px;
    height:0;
    border-top:1px solid;
    margin-top:-1px;
    position:absolute;
    top:1em;
    left:0
}
.tree ul li:last-child:before {
    background:#fff;
    height:auto;
    top:1em;
    bottom:0
}
.indicator {
    margin-right:5px;
}
.tree li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#369;
}
.tree li button, .tree li button:active, .tree li button:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#369;
    border:none;
    background:transparent;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul id="tree1">
                <li><a href="#">TECH</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                        <li>Employees
                            <ul>
                                <li>Reports
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Report1</li>
                                        <li>Report2</li>
                                        <li>Report3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Human Resources</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>XRP
                    <ul>
                        <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                        <li>Employees
                            <ul>
                                <li>Reports
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Report1</li>
                                        <li>Report2</li>
                                        <li>Report3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Human Resources</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
       
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maybe you are looking for. See the [working codepen](https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/jzxJzb?editors=1111)

```
tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(this).attr('href') !== null) {
            // redirect
            console.log('redirect');
            window.location.href = this.attr('href');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('li').click();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Tan Duong, it's totally perfect answers. Now `<ul>` or `<li>` have attribute  `a href`, it will be go the the link instead show/hide action. Thanks bro again.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code and the comments you can delete the below section which is responsible for adding a click event on those anchor `<a>` tags that shows/hides the tree below, it also prevents the default behavior, which in this case would be to follow the link.

```
//fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).closest('li').click();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```